# Mesh deform Large file size

Tags: mesh, modifiers, blend-files

Recently, I used mesh deform modifier with armature to animate a character, but after clicking on the "bind" button, I saw that not all the mesh was deformed by the cage, so I clicked "unbind."
I've repeated this action about 7 times and finally I got the results that I want. BUT the problem is after saving my project, my blend file became very very large: about 800Mb.

Why does it happen? How to reduce my blend file size?

Comment: How many objects are in your scene? What was the file size before you noticed the huge jump?

Comment: Before the huge jump, the blend file was about 60Mb, I think there was about 20 meshes in my scene

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems it's some kind of a bug in blender. If you have subdivision modifiers applied to the mesh put surface deform before it. This helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unbinding the Modifier should reduce your file size to the previous 60Mb,
but the deformation data from your binding will be deleted.

Same with the Surface Deform Modifier.
I recommend to keep the modifier unbinded and bind it only before final render (if your workflow allows that).

Answer (score -1):

Apply the Mesh Modifier and the size will be good.